# Laravel best or effective way to handle if else statement

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

i am stuck a bit, i have lot of if else statement handeling, and i will need to use this in more the none page, so handeling it in the view is not a good idea (and read about it its not a good idea)

So what im am stuck with i have 2 tables.

```
user
users_details
```

`User table` stores basic login information and and the user `details` has the following fields

```
user_id
first_name  
last_name   
company 
location    
experience  
compensation    
about   
gender  
year    
day 
month   
profile_image
```

my relations

**User model**

```
public function detail()
{
   return $this->has_one('Detail');
}
```

**Details model**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongs_to('User');
}
```

So what im stuck with is how to handle the object to r`eturn experience, compensation` because those what i will need on more than one page, at first i did this in my controller

```
public function get_index($username = null)
{

   $user = User::get_profile($username);

   if (is_null($user))  return Response::error('404');

   switch ($user->detail->experience) {
    case 1:
        $user->detail->experience = "No experience";
    break;

    case 2:
        $user->detail->experience = "Some experience";
    break;

    case 3:
        $user->detail->experience = "Experienced";
    break;

    case 4:
        $user->detail->experience = "Very experienced";
    break;

   }

    switch ($user->detail->compensation) {
    case 1:
        $user->detail->compensation = "Any";
    break;

    case 2:
        $user->detail->compensation = "Depends on Assignment ";
    break;

    case 3:
        $user->detail->compensation = "Paid Assignments Only ";
    break;

    case 4:
        $user->detail->compensation = "Time for Print ";
    break;

   }

   $this->layout->title = 'Profile' . ' ' . $username ;

   $this->layout->content = View::make( 'user.profile' )->with( 'user', $user );

}
```

And i know this is the worts idea i should come up with because it wont solve my problem, not effective and i still need to duplicate.

So could someone show me and example and effective way to handle these?

Would be grateful, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is weird, indeed.

But, you have 2 ways:

1) Define tables for answers and join with your user table, so SQL result will return string, not ID

2) If you still want for a some reason to associate ID to Text on code level you can do following:

Define method in details model, like compensation_str() which will make this switch, same for expierence. And in each place you need to display this text you call this method ($user->details->compensation_str())

Comment: I like the second option. If you want this logic to exist, then it should be in the model. I can see why you are going down this road. The DB is highly optimized using ints over varchar and splitting tertiary data from primary... but IMO using an ORM is really about reducing development time/cost and with that, conceding a bit on the DB design.

Comment: i went with the first option, because, i will need to be able to edit these options through admin panel, the first option was the better solution